# percentage in mongo/ aggregation over collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, aggregate-functions

*Updated 01/03/2022 with real data sample*

Hello
I've this kind of data (1.5M of lines stored in a mongo server) 

I've to calculate the daily percentage of failed device (by date and classes of article) , and also the rate of devices in normal status (also by date and by class of articles). 

**Data stored in mongo**

```
 [{
  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_1",
  "NumberOfArticles": 9,
  "Status": "OK",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 ",

},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_1",
  "NumberOfArticles": 1,
  "Status": "Failed",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 ",

},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_2",
  "NumberOfArticles": 8,
  "Status": "Failed",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 " :,

},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_2",
  "NumberOfArticles": 8,
  "Status": "OK",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 ",
  
},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_1",
  "NumberOfArticles": 1,
  "Status": "OK",
  "DateOfExtraction": "13/01/2022 ", 
}
]
```

**Target**

````
{[
  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_1",
  "NumberOfArticles": 9,
  "Status": "OK",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 ",
  "percent" :  0.9 #( = (9/(1+9) ) 90% of 'CODE_1' devices are ok  the 11/01/2022
},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_1",
  "NumberOfArticles": 1,
  "Status": "Failed",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 ",
  "percent":  0.1 # 1/(1+9) # here are the 10% of failed 'CODE_1' for 11/01/2022
},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_2",
  "NumberOfArticles": 8,
  "Status": "Failed",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 " :,
  "percent" : 0.5 # 8/(8+8 # another device : 50% of 'CODE_2' devices are failed this day
},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_2",
  "NumberOfArticles": 8,
  "Status": "OK",
  "DateOfExtraction": "11/01/2022 ",
  "percent" : 0.5 # 8/(8+8)
  
},
{

  "CODE_ARTICLE": "CODE_1",
  "NumberOfArticles": 1,
  "Status": "OK",
  "DateOfExtraction": "13/01/2022 ", 
  "percent" : 1 # no failed devices code_1 this day
}
] ```

Do you have any idea how I can proceed with mongo aggregations ?

Many many thanks !
````

Comment: Clarification: you want the percent by date for all articles in the total collection, so what do you want to do with status and ID_article?

Comment: I'd like to analyse the failure rate over time / article

Comment: what kind of calculate can make 0.30 in your testing data which only have NbOfarticles 2 and 21 in 21/10/2021 ?

Comment: Sorry, I just typed it too quickly and I've not made  any calculations: you 'right percent would be 2/23*100 % . But how to do it in mongo aggregate() ?

Answer (score 1):

**count each document**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$DateExtraction",
      sortBy: {},
      output: {
        s: {
          $sum: "$NbOfarticles",
          window: {
            documents: [
              "unbounded",
              "unbounded"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "Percent": {
        $round: [
          {
            "$divide": [
              "$NbOfarticles",
              "$s"
            ]
          },
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/De_0ojJAn2D)

Comment: Good use of a v5.0 feature.  Note that the values shown for `sortBy` and `window` are defaults so they can be removed entirely to make the pipeline more compact.

Comment: Hello all
Thank you for your answers : for the % calculus , how I could proceed for having the daily % by date and by article (ie the total has to be calculated for one given class of article)

Comment: @Far31 It would be better if you can edit your question with a `valid json` result taht you expected.

Answer (score 1):

For those not yet on v5.0, here is an alternative that uses the "group and push $$CURRENT" approach to hang on to all the inputs that go into a group so they can be used later.

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$DateExtraction", total: {$sum:"$NbOfarticles"},
              X: {$push: "$$CURRENT"} }}
    ,{$unwind: "$X"}

    // At this point, you can see all the raw materials for the percentage are
    // now at hand.  Reading this next stage "inside out", we first compute
    // pct, then assign it to key 'pct' in a new object, which we then merge
    // with the existing object (effectively, this is 'X.pct = calc'), and
    // lastly we turn the full-fledged 'X' object -- which includes '_id' and
    // everything else -- into the root doc: 
    ,{$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$mergeObjects: ["$X",
                       {"pct":{$round:[{$divide:["$X.NbOfarticles","$total"]},2]}}
                                              ]}
    }}
]);
```

Here is a variation that moves the work into a `$map` before the `$unwind`.  Operating on the array `X` inside the doc instead of as unwound objects gives us the additional opportunity to cut down the size of the array and thus create fewer new objects, although in this example we do not do that.  Note that the heart of the matter (calc pct, set up a new object with just `pct:calc`, and merge) is the *same* for both approaches.

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$DateExtraction", total: {$sum:"$NbOfarticles"}, X: {$push: "$$CURRENT"} }}

    ,{$project: {X: {$map: {input: "$X",
        in: {$mergeObjects: [ "$$this",
              {'pct':{$round:[{$divide:["$$this.NbOfarticles","$total"]},2]} }
                            ]
            }
                           }}
    }}

    ,{$unwind: "$X"}
    ,{$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$X"}}
]);
```